# multi match elastic search in multi word field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have for example following documents in elastic search:

```
{ make: 'honda',
  model: 'civic 5-door'
  year: '2011'
}

{ make: 'honda',
  model: 'CIVIC TOURER 5-DOOR '
  year: '2011'
}

{ make: 'honda',
  model: 'JAZZ 5-DOOR'
  year: '2012'
}

{ make: 'mazda',
  model: 'some multi word name'
  year: '2012'
}
```

I want to make a single search bar which could search across all the three fields. I tried the following query:

```
$query = 'some query string'

        $results = $search->search([
            'index' => 'cars',
            'body' => [
                "query" =>[
                    'multi_match' => [
                        "query" => $query,
                        "type" => "cross_fields",
                        "analyzer"=> "standard",
                        "fields" => ['model', 'make', 'year']                        ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

when i use search query like 'honda 2011', the query returns the result (it matches the query terms in 'make', and 'year'), but if i just type 'civic' (see the multi word field 'model'), it does not show any result. Why is the search into multi work field not working? Am i missing something? Please help.

My index mapping looks like the following:

```
$params = ['index' => 'cars'];

        $params['body'] = [
            'mappings' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'body_type' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword'
                    ],
                    'fuel_type' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword'
                    ],
                    'engine_size' => [
                        'type' => 'short'
                    ],
                    'make' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword'
                    ],
                    'model' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword'
                    ],
                    'dealership' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword'
                    ],
                    'transmission' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword'
                    ],
                    'colour' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword',
                    ],
                    'location' => [
                        'type' => 'geo_point'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: Can you show your index mapping as well please?

Comment: @Val I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for multi_match to work you need to change your `model` field to `text` instead of `keyword`.

With a `keyword` field you can only run exact matches because keyword field values are not analyzed.

Try changing to

```
                'model' => [
                    'type' => 'text'
                ],
```

And then reindex your data and your query will work.

Comment: Thanks you. Additionally i also had to do "fielddata" => true. Then it worked.

Comment: I don't think fielddata is necessary for multimatch, only if you also do aggregations or sorting on that field.